# Compiler error MT2002: when IOS app (Xamarin) references class in VB.NET Windows forms project

Tags: c#, vb.net, xamarin.ios

I get the compiler error below when my C# IOS XAMARIN project references a method in my vb.net windows forms project.

Started with

ERROR IS...………………..
 error MT2002: Failed to resolve "System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase" reference from "System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"

Comment: why is your iOS project referencing a WinForms project?  The WinForms projects is going to have dependencies that just don't exist in iOS.  If you just want to share some common code between them, you should break that code out into a separate library

Comment: I just broke it into a new vb.net win forms class lib with only the shared code, and still get same error MT2002.

Comment: does that class use ApplicationSettingsBase?  That is not supported in iOS (see the docs page, it has a list of supported frameworks: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: You will probably end up having to port the code to use libraries that are compatible with Xamarin.